# StackApps twitter account

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, twitter, stackapps

Now that all the Stack Exchange sites (except the trilogy) have Twitter accounts, they've all tweeted except [StackApps](http://twitter.com/#!/stackapps).

It would be good if this Twitter account tweeted the newest "questions" tagged [app] (and library?).

Comment: @Kevin two and half years later, is it still planned? ;)

Comment: I believe this is something we're eventually going to do, but most likely next year.

Comment: @TimPost Whatever happened to this?

Comment: @BCLC We no longer create them per-site because we keep setting off Twitter's fraud / abuse systems when we interact with so many accounts via the API from a single origin. At the time this was written we were looking into why per-site accounts kept getting suspended, and, well, eventually figured it out.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. As a guy who has Twitter only a few times since I first made an account: LOL